# Using Dagger2 with flavors and androidTest source set

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am attempting to write instrumentation tests for an app that uses Dagger2. The app has several build types and one of them is called automation. The automation build type is also set as the testBuildType in the build.gradle.

The activity I'd like to test has a Presenter injected that depends on a Repository. What I'd like to do is inject a real repository when I'm building any build type except for automation and then when I build the automation build variant I'd like to inject a mock Repository.

In my androidTest source set I've created a MockComponent and a MockModule which create mock a mock version of the Repository. What I figured I would be able to do is build an instance of MockComponent and use it to provide a Mock Repository. The problem seems to be that if MockComponent and MockModule are in the androidTest source set then Dagger never generates the DaggerMockComponent class when I build. If I move MockComponent and MockModule to the automation source set then Dagger does generate the classes however then I'm in a position where I want to add an inject method to MockComponent so that I can inject an object into my activity test class but MockComponent can't get see the activity test class because it's in the android source set.

Any ideas why Dagger won't generate the DaggerMockComponent class when it's in the androidTest source set?

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being that in my build.gradle file I needed to include a dependency for the androidTest source set. Normally you use

```
androidTestCompile "com.package.version:1.2.3"
```

But for dagger you have to use apt so the line looks like:

```
androidTestApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
```

The really confusing thing about this was that since I am using a build type (automation) for my testBuildType I was able to add dagger code to the automation source set and dagger could compile it b/c it wasn't in the androidTest source set. Then I tried to add the dagger code to the androidTest source set and suddenly it was like it was invisible to the dagger compiler b/c it would never generate the dagger classes for the components that were specified in the androidTest source set.